# Two-layer bag vs. bilayer bag vs. double-wall bag vs.

Tags: word-choice

I'm translating a paragraph that describes drug product packaging:

> Packaging: From 50 g to 500 g in a transparent polyethylene bag (either **double-wall** or bag-in-bag).

Which would be the better choice: "**double-wall**", "**bilayer**" or "**two-layer**"? The meaning is, the polyethylene bag has two similar layers in order to ensure the safety of the product (alternatively, two single-wall bags could be used, hence "bag-in-bag").

Maybe all three options are okay? I'm looking for one that would sound more natural to native speakers.

Comment: "Double-wall" is probably best, because I prefer it.

Comment: You could also call them **two-ply**.

Comment: I agree with @P.E.Dant that `double-wall` is the best usage for this situation. Because the bag consists of 2 walls, it sounds more natural that describing the bag walls as layers.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - thank you, P.E., and I would be doubly grateful if you posted your comment as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, tovarisch, but if I were to post _"**Double-wall** is best, because I prefer it"_ as an answer, no-one would be pleased except you and I.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about industry/context dependent terminology, and is not about learning English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that industry has specific terminology that it uses to describe two-layered packaging bags.  You should probably do some research and use the term most commonly used by those in that industry.

Also, there can be legal repercussions if you describe something incorrectly -- for example, if an expensive product is damaged in shipping because someone used the wrong kind of bag.  So not only is using the "correct" term more easily understood, it prevents mistakes and covers your employer from liability.

[I would start here](http://www.tricorbraun.com/what-were-about/tricorbraun-university/packaging-terms) and peruse the list to see what jumps out at you (already I see "double-walled bags" listed under "bags").

Comment: I agree, but this should be a comment not an answer, as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user3169 telling someone "this isn't a part of everyday English, so you should peruse dictionaries directly relevant to the topic you're talking about" isn't an answer?  Strange logic, there ...

Comment: In your answer, you say "My guess is..." and "You should probably do some research..." along with some legal advice. Not Q/A format in my book. I doubt the question could be answered without an example product and some technical expertise.